# Can I loop a list of a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to loop thru a list of products, where the list is a `SELECT` statement. Right now it is just a `INT` variable that is incremented:

```
DECLARE @i INT
SELECT @i = 0

WHILE( @i < 100 )
BEGIN
    ...

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

This is not what I want. How can I modify this so that `@i` is a element of a statement, something along the lines of (pseudo-ish):

```
DECLARE @ids List<INT>
SELECT @ids = (SELECT p.Id FROM Products p WHERE p.Active = 1)

FOR(@id in @ids)
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

The `BEGIN END` section is a couple of several lines of statements pulling out this and that with products with id of @i from the first. But I thought I could create a list of active products instead of adding the AND p.Active = 1 to all the statements in the `BEGIN END` section. This is for a Microsoft SQL Server using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What database is it against? SQL Server, MySQL, something else? e.g. SQL Server has cursors, which would let you do what you want (I think).

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Please, tag your DBMS.

Comment: Hi @MarcinJuraszek its agains Microsoft SQL. Ill update the post

Comment: You can work with cursors if you are using sql server.

Comment: Presumably there is no need in while loop/cursor. Many things can be accomplished with a single `select` statement. Elaborate what's inside your `begin-end` may be we can help you with that.

Comment: I agree with both comments above. While it is possible to use a cursor, looping might not be the best solution. In fact, it rarely is the best solution. SQL works best on a set based approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below 2 options, let me know if any error occur.

> Option 1.
>   Declare variable table with extra identity column, then loop this
>   variable  table if there is any data.

```
DECLARE @VarTable TABLE (ORDER_ID int IDENTITY(1,1), ID INT not null)
INSERT INTO @VarTable
SELECT p.Id 
FROM Products p 
WHERE p.Active = 1

DECLARE @order_id int = 1
DECLARE @max_order_id int = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ORDER_ID),0) FROM @VarTable)
WHILE (@order_id <= @max_order_id)
BEGIN
    -- do your stuff
    SET @order_id = @order_id + 1
END
```

> Option 2. You can use cursor to loop through IDs from your select
>   statement.

```
DECLARE @ID INT

DECLARE CRS_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT P.Id 
FROM Products P
WHERE P.Active = 1

OPEN CRS_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_CURSOR INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- below line to test only
    SELECT @ID AS CurrentID
    -- do your stuff based on current @ID

    FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_CURSOR INTO @ID
END

CLOSE CRS_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE CRS_CURSOR
```

Comment: @fUrious. Which option did you pick?